# Have a popup image link to a URL in shadowbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

In shadowbox, how would I go about linking a popup image to a URL?

The HTML is

```
<a href="/images/flyer.jpg" rel="shadowbox">text here</a>
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Shadowbox.init();
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Have you included the JavaScript and CSS files correctly? your markup looks correct for the library in question.

Comment: Yea, i've included the files correctly. The image does popup, but I wanted to know if there was a way for the image that pops up to have a url attached to it.

Comment: Yes - once you have the popup and know what the markup is you can write something to prepend and append, or wrap, the proper markup to make image a link. Have you examined the DOM when the image is displayed?